# java.lang.ArrarIndexOutOfBoundsException:11

Tags: java, jdbc-odbc

I have the following code which compiles fine but when it runs then it throws the exception that java.lang.ArrarIndexOutOfBoundsException:11, please if you could help what is wrong it would be a great help.

The code is:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import java.sql.*;

public class Pro implements ActionListener

{

    JTextField t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13;
    JButton b1,b2;
     public Pro()
        {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();

            JLabel l1 = new JLabel("SNo.");
            JLabel l2 = new JLabel("OPANo");
            JLabel l3 = new JLabel("CollegeName");
            JLabel l4 = new JLabel("ProjectName");
            JLabel l5 = new JLabel("SanctionNoDate");
            JLabel l6 = new JLabel("TotalOutlayInLakhs)");
            JLabel l7 = new JLabel("ProjectDuration");
            JLabel l8 = new JLabel("AmountReleased");
            JLabel l9 = new JLabel("BalanceToBeReleased");
            JLabel l10 = new JLabel("PRSGsHeld");
            JLabel l11 = new JLabel("NextPRSGDue");
            JLabel l12 = new JLabel("CompletionMonth");
            JLabel l13 = new JLabel("Status");

            t1 = new JTextField(20);
            t1.setEnabled(false);
            t2 = new JTextField(20);
            t3 = new JTextField(20);
            t4 = new JTextField(20);
            t5 = new JTextField(20);
            t6 = new JTextField(20);
            t7 = new JTextField(20);
            t8 = new JTextField(20);
            t9 = new JTextField(20);
            t10 = new JTextField(20);
            t11 = new JTextField(20);
            t12 = new JTextField(20);
            t13 = new JTextField(20);

            b1 = new JButton("Reset");
            b2 = new JButton("Insert");

            b1.addActionListener(this);
            b2.addActionListener(this);

            JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
            p1.add(l1);p1.add(t1);
            p1.add(l2);p1.add(t2);
            p1.add(l3);p1.add(t3);
            p1.add(l4);p1.add(t4);
            p1.add(l5);p1.add(t5);
            p1.add(l6);p1.add(t6);
            p1.add(l7);p1.add(t7);
            p1.add(l8);p1.add(t8);
            p1.add(l9);p1.add(t9);
            p1.add(l10);p1.add(t10);
            p1.add(l11);p1.add(t11);
            p1.add(l12);p1.add(t12);
            p1.add(l13);p1.add(t13);
            p1.add(b1);p1.add(b2);

            p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(14,2));

            f.add(p1);
                    f.pack();
                    f.setResizable(false);
                    f.setVisible(true);
            }
                public int getMaxSNO()
                {
                    int sno=0;
                    String path ="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=doit.mdb";
                            try
                            {
                                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(path);

                                Statement stat = con.createStatement();
                                ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT max(Sno) from project");
                                if(rs.next())
                                {
                                    sno=rs.getInt(1);
                                }
                            }
        catch(Exception e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
                }
                return sno;
                }
        public boolean isAlpha(String str)
            {
                boolean result = false;

                for(int i=0;i!=str.length();i++)
                {
                    int ch = str.charAt(i);

                    if((ch>=65 && ch<=91) || (ch>=97 && ch<=122))
                    {
                        result = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
    return result;
            }
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==b1)
        {
            t1.setText("");
            t2.setText("");
            t3.setText("");
            t4.setText("");
            t5.setText("");
            t6.setText("");
            t7.setText("");
            t8.setText("");
            t9.setText("");
            t10.setText("");
            t11.setText("");
            t12.setText("");
            t13.setText("");
        }
    else if(e.getSource()==b2)
    {
        String name = t3.getText();
                    boolean b1 = isAlpha(name);

                    if(b1)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                    String path ="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=doit.mdb";

                            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(path);

                            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT into project(OPANo, CollegeName, ProjectName, SanctionNoDate, TotalOutlayInLakhs, ProjectDuration, AmountReleased, BalanceToBeReleased, PRSGsHeld, NextPRSGDue, CompletionMonth, Status) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");



                            ps.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(t2.getText()));
                            ps.setString(2, t3.getText());
                            ps.setString(3, t4.getText());
                            ps.setString(4, t5.getText());
                            ps.setString(5, t6.getText());
                            ps.setString(6, t7.getText());
                            ps.setString(7, t8.getText());
                            ps.setString(8, t9.getText());
                            ps.setString(9, t10.getText());
                            ps.setString(10, t11.getText());
                            ps.setString(11, t12.getText());
                            ps.setString(12, t13.getText());


                            int rows = ps.executeUpdate();
                            if(rows>0)
                            {
                                con.close();
                                int sno=getMaxSNO();

                                t1.setText(String.valueOf(sno));
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Inserted");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed");
                            }
                            con.close();
                        }
                        catch(Exception ae)
                                        {
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ae.toString());
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Name");
                                    }
                                }
                            }


                            public static void main(String args[])
                            {
                                Pro obj = new Pro();
                            }
```

}

Comment: You've given way more code than you really need to demonstrate the problem, and haven't even shown us which line of code is throwing the exception. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: A stack trace would help (so you can pinpoint the program line number where it errors).

Comment: @Akriti it would help if you could print the stack trace for us to see whats going on. I agree you need to show what lines throwing the exception. At the moment the exception is being thrown by some method where we don't know what it is.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
// Reformatted
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT into project(OPANo, CollegeName, ProjectName, SanctionNoDate, " + 
    "TotalOutlayInLakhs, ProjectDuration, AmountReleased, " + 
    "BalanceToBeReleased, PRSGsHeld, NextPRSGDue, CompletionMonth, Status) " + 
    "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Count the question marks, then count the number of values you're trying to specify...

(Then note that you're calling `ps.setString(12, t13.getText())` - confirming that you really meant there to be 12 parameters, not 11...)

Comment: Exactly, nice catch. +1. OP needs to add one more Question mark `?` in the query.

Comment: That's going to throw a java.sql.SQLException saying that the parameter bindings are invalid.

Comment: @Anthony: Ideally, yes... but I *suspect* that's what's wrong.